# Set CSS class for several ID

Tags: html, css

I have done the following:

```
#my-el .some-class {
    width: 10%;
}
```

That works but now I'd like to apply the same class to the element #my-new-el. I've tried:

```
#my-el #my-new-el .some-class {
    width: 10%;
}
```

But this does not work. What would be the correct syntax to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

If `.some-class` only applies to descendents of `#my-el` and `#my-new-el` then you need to specify the two selectors in full, separated by a comma:

```
#my-el .some-class, #my-new-el .some-class  {
    width: 10%;
}
```